# IP validation regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

The condition is that the default IP address must be possible.

as an example

- `*`
- `127.0.0.*`
  It should be possible.

there is only one asterisk
It should also be possible that the last is a asterisk.

Comment: Please add: 1. sample inputs, 2. sample outputs, 3. code you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, your question seems to indicate only IPv4 addresses.
I created the most readable version I could think off, which makes it easier to explain, while also preventing leading zero's:

```
^(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]|\*))|\*)$
```

**Explained:**

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}
```

- 3 time repeating group

  - `25[0-5]` -> 250 to 255
  - `2[0-4][0-9]` -> 200 to 249
  - `1[0-9][0-9]` -> 100 to 199
  - `[1-9][0-9]` -> 10 to 99
  - `[0-9]` 0 to 9
  - . followed by a dot

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]|\*))
```

- Same group which also allows a * (`|\*´)
- Without a trailing dot

```
^(...|\*)$
```

- All of this is wrapped in an OR so * is also valid